# Pear Email Validation

Tags: php, pear

I am trying to create a simple webstore which has a couple of forms which customers need to fill. After they are filled, I validate them using Pear Validate.php.

```
$validate = new Validate();

$options = array("check_domain"=>true,"use_rfc822"=>true);

$test = $validate->email("$epost",$ehdot);
if (!($test)) {
    $checks = false;
    echo 'EMAIL IS WRONG </p>';

}
```

$epost being the email customer inserts into a email form.
For some reason, it throws an error like this:

```
Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by 
reference in /home2-3/e/anon/public_html/php/verkkostore/Validate.php on line 586
```

Here is the code from Validate.php from line 586

```
$domain = preg_replace('/[^-a-z.0-9]/i', '', array_pop(explode('@', $email)));
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `$pop = array_pop(explode('@', $email)); $domain = preg_replace('/[^-a-z.0-9]/i', '', $pop);` might work.

Comment: ^^^ working, yes/no/gone to lunch?

Comment: Feel free to go to lunch. I need to go in a moment anyway

Comment: Did you try my suggestion? Lunch is passed already ;)

Comment: It works when I type in a wrong type of email like "asd", but not when I'm sending an email with a clearly wrong domain address like "ben@asiodjapsja.com".

Comment: It got rid of the initial error though.

Comment: I did some more checks and found out that It doesn't get rid of them after all. If there is wrong data on other forms, user has to stay on the page and retype them. In this case, if the email form has been given the right type of address, same error appears. This time the error is in line which has this part of your code: $pop = array_pop(explode('@', $email));

Answer (score 1):

Okay this is how I fixed it. Thank you for your help, it got me on a right path!

```
$array = explode('@', $email);
$pop = array_pop($array);
$domain = preg_replace('/[^-a-z.0-9]/i', '', $pop);
```